# Lightroom: Apply the editing to the original file

Tags: migration, lightroom

I have a large library of photos in Lightroom.

How I can apply my editing to the **original photos** massively (like 77k photos)?

The purpose of this is:

- Migrate to another photo library without losing the editing (like Acdsee)
- View the photos outside Lightroom
- Streamline the database

The only way I found is this:

1. Export the photos
2. Reimport it (automatically)
3. Delete the old files manually on library

But It is very hard to do in a complex directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't why this should be any more difficult because you your filing system.

Either your directory tree is complex and you struggle to find the photos you want to take outside of Lightroom or it is easy to select these photos.

If it is a complex process to select the 77K images that you need then it will take you time to find the images you need to export. But the effort stops there.

The other two steps are automatically taken care of.

Export photos as catalog including negatives (edits, keywords, collections etc are kept)

If it is necessary to delete these from current catalog just save the ones you have selected for export as a separate collection

Open the new catalog and verify

Return to the old catalog and delete

Import into Acdsee (apparently it works).

Hope this helps.